# How to split large length of item text of dropdown list into paragraph in html

Tags: c#, html, paragraph, dropdownbox

**How to split large length of item text of dropdown list into paragraph in html.**

```
<select id="s7"  name="size">
option value="1">My problem is that the column is not wide enough to display 
                 the contents in the drop-down list.</option>
option value="2">bxcvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv</option>
option value="3">Square Pop-Up </option>
option value="4">Vertical Rectangle </option>
</select>
```

Comment: try using jquery or java script

Comment: Welcome to http://stackoverflow.com/. Please explain your question bit more. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The exact problem is - If the drop down item text length is bigger like 'bxcvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvbxcvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv' then when we are going for selecting the text then browser scrolling is increases due to big length of text so i would like to split the text into paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
<select id="s7"  name="size" style="word-wrap:break-word;width:300px;">
    <option value="1">My problem is that the column is not wide enough to display 
             the contents in the drop-down list.</option>
    <option value="2">bxcvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv</option>
    <option value="3">Square Pop-Up </option>
    <option value="4">Vertical Rectangle </option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a short description for the item, and move the long text into title attribute. When users move their mouse on the item, they will see the long text.

```
<option value="1" title="My problem is that the column is not wide enough to display the contents in the drop-down list.">short description</option>
```